# Getting attribute from java class in Servlet(doesn't see forwarded request in JSP)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm studying Head First Servlets and JSP and being stuck with this problem.
The topic starts with page 480 of this book.
I am trying to develop servlet without IDEs.
This servlet should show list of films in a tabular form.

Here goes my code
`MoviesList.java`:

```
package com.model;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MovieList extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
        String[] movieList = {"Hannah Montana", "Kill Bill", "Terminator 2"};
        req.setAttribute("movieList", movieList);
    }
}
```

`Show.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html><body>
<strong> Movie list:</strong>
<br><br>

<table>
     <c:forEach var="movie" items="${movieList}">
          <tr>
            <td>${movie}</td>
         </tr>
    </c:ForEach>    
</table>

</html></body>
```

Thing Tomcat8 shows in a browser:

```
type Exception report
```

Message: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

`exception`:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:75)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:243)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:124)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:411)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1430)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.24 logs.

I cannot manage to bind code from my java class to jsp. Do I miss the DD or?

```
Now I solved it, thanks a lot!
I have got nex question:
It renders only text "Movie list:" and nothing more
How I fix that?
```

Now I changed my servlet code so it forwards request to Show.jsp and recompiled my class, rebooted tomcat but it still doesn't work...

```
req.setAttribute("movieList", movieList);


     try {

  getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(

    "Show.jsp").forward(req ,res );



} catch (ServletException e) {

  // TODO Auto-generated catch block

  e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

  // TODO Auto-generated catch block

  e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info   where did you put jar or jars?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean read the info page and download the JSTL jar and put into your lib folder.

Comment: this one passes?
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1-javadoc

Comment: Thank you, already solved this!
But right now question is where did my films go!
It shows only "Movie list:" and nothing more

Comment: Tell us the flow of your web app. How did you get from your Servlet to Show.jsp?  Since your movieList is in request scope, you would need to forward from Your Servlet to Show.jsp.  Alternatively, change scope of movieList to session.

Comment: I did it wrong apparently) Please check this upper , I added code

Comment: I am confused. Maybe you should create new question.

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot=)
I will try to figure it  out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Tomcat will not include JSTL library.
So you should download the JSTL jars(standard.jar and jstl.jar) and put them in your application's WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: I have added javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1-javadoc to my WEB-INF/lib folder
and now it shows:

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.Show_jsp
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176) .......

Am I wrong with downloaded file?
I got it on http://search.maven.org/#browse|-1002239620

Comment: It seems I gained some progress.
Just read [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) about JSTL thread and now it shows me next:
/Show.jsp (line: 11, column: 1) The end tag "&lt;/c:ForEach" is unbalanced

Comment: Thank you so much!
I solved this </c:ForEach> closing tag must be of lowerCase: <c:forEach>!
It renders now "Movie list:" and nothing more...(
Did I miss the scope or?